# Como mudar a cor de um Hyperlink no android studio?

Tags: android, link, textview

Consigo fazer o Hyperlink perfeitamente, **o problema é que a sua cor não está contrastando bem com o background da minha aplicação** (segue imagem):

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Gostaria de saber como modificar a sua cor, já que mudar a cor do texto do textView não resulta, pois **o hyperlink sempre fica rosa**.

**Código da activity:**

```js
package genesysgeneration.font4;

import android.graphics.Typeface;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.text.Html;
import android.text.method.LinkMovementMethod;
import android.widget.CheckBox;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private TextView tvLink;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        tvLink=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.tvLink);
        tvLink.setText(Html.fromHtml("<a href=\"http://www.google.com\">google</a>"));
        tvLink.setMovementMethod(LinkMovementMethod.getInstance());

    }
}
```

**xml da activity:**

```js
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/activity_main"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:background="@drawable/back"
    tools:context="genesysgeneration.font4.MainActivity">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvLink"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="133dp"
        android:text="google"
        android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
        android:textSize="24sp" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Para alteração da cor padrão do *hyperlink* em um `TextView` é usado o atributo `android:textColorLink`. Você pode definir a cor baseado no formato padrão das cores: `#rgb`, `#argb`, `#rrggbb` ou `#aarrggbb`. Veja abaixo como é simples:

Exemplo no XML:

```
<TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Um texto qualquer"
        android:textColorLink="#ff0000" />
```

Exemplo programaticamente:

```
textView.setLinkTextColor(Color.RED);
```

Veja mais detalhes [na documentação](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#attr_android:textColorLink)<sup>(en)</sup>.